# basic authentication https proxy sockets displaying tlsv1 decode error after connection established

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, http-proxy, python-sockets

I am attempting to connect to an https authenticated proxy with basic auth (user:pass with b64 encoding). I was able to make non-authed proxies work fine, but i recently bought proxies and now i need to make authed work. It seemed simple, all i had to do was add a "proxy-authorization" header and it would work. After doing this it worked, well it gave me a "200 connection established" response. After doing this, i attempt to ssl wrap the socket with the "ssl" lib. This causes me to receive the following error: "tlsv1 decode error". After looking at some stack posts, i figured i should change the protocol version being used, I tried to use every other available version which for some reason still resulted in the error i said above (this was weird because i was not using "tlsv1".

```
credentials = base64.encodebytes(b"user:pass").decode().strip(r"\n")
s.connect((proxy[0], int(proxy[1])))
s.send(f"CONNECT site.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nProxy-Authorization: Basic {credentials}\r\nHost: site.com\r\n\r\n".encode())
connect_response = s.recv(4096)
print(connect_response)
s = wrap_socket(s)
```

Upon doing more research, i figured out that it could have something to do with the "realm" response header. I could not find any docs on this and i dont know what its used for. This makes me believe that i am doing something wrong , and i should have more steps before i attempt to wrap the socket.
My question is why am i getting this error/traceback when attempting to wrap the socket and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you print out the request before you send it you will see this:

```
b'CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nProxy-Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz\n\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n'
```

Notice the `\n\r\n` at the end of the `Proxy-Authorization` header. This is simply wrong, i.e. it should be `\r\n` only.

Due to the extraneous `\n` these characters get actually get interpreted as the end of the HTTP header and the rest `Host: google.com\r\n\r\n` will remain unread by the server for now. It gets only read when the TLS handshake gets expected, i.e. the `Host: google.com\r\n\r\n` will be interpreted as part of the TLS ClientHello by the server and thus the TLS handshake will fail.

The fix is to eliminate the wrong `\n` at the end. While you've tried this with `strip(r"\n")` the correct way would be `strip("\n")` only: you want to eliminate the 1-byte character `"\n"` and not the 2-byte string `r"\n"`.

Comment: always seems to be the super little things, thanks man it worked. I have always used r"\n" but now i know why i shouldnt in some cases.